# Radiobutton clicks and unclicks automatically when click() method is used

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to raise the click event of a radio button using the `click()` method in Selenium WebDriver. The element is identified and clicked, however within a fraction of a second, the click is performed again and the radio button is unselected.

Doing the click operation multiple times repeats the select and un-select that many times.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpathexpression")).click();
```

Comment: When you try clicking it manually does your selection remain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is resolved when i use the submit()  method along with the click() method on the radio button. By using submit() along with click() im able to retain the selction of the radio button.

This issue happens only during automation. On selecting the radiobutton manually, the selection is retained.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
//If u want to check whether the radio button is selected or not
if(driver.findElement(By.id("xpathexpression")).isSelected()){
   ..................
   ..................
}
else
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("xpathexpression")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

and if this will not solve problem, try to share few line codes.

Comment: I tried the above code and also by using a while loop. The issue is that the click() method selects the radio button and immediately the button is unselected. This happens infinitely in a while loop. The application is on Pega (BPM tool) in which a javascript is called everytime a radio button is selected. 

while(!element.isSelected()){ element.click(); Thread.sleep(5000);}
--rest of the code which proceeds with the flow--

In this case, the code never comes out of the while loop.

Comment: I worried is that the behaviour of code to select and unselect radio button at regular interval, or its happening for automation only.